# Task status WaitingForActivation - what does this mean?

Tags: c#, task

I am starting wpf tasks with the way below

```
var newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
fcStartSubPageCrawl(srMainSiteURL, srMainSiteId);
}).ContinueWith((t) =>
{
  var aggException = t.Exception.Flatten();
 foreach (var exception in aggException.InnerExceptions)
   csPages.LogException(exception.ToString());
},
TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Now when i check the task status

like this (new tasks assigned to task list) :

```
  if (tskLocalTaskList[i].IsCompleted == false)
```

I am seeing that task status = WaitingForActivation

what does this mean ? And why it is waiting activation ?

C# 4.0 WPF

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WaitingForActivation is the time the task resides between a call to the Start method and the moment in which the task gets scheduled by the Task scheduler. So directly after a call to the start method of a task, the tasks status is being set to WaitingForActivation and a call to scheduler.AddWork is made. In here, the Task is either scheduler (WaitingToRun) or run immidiatly.

Oh, and this has nothing to do with WPF, Tasks are a part of the BCL

Comment: How do i make the task start immediately ?

Comment: This is due to your statement ContinueWith. This creates a new Task which you assign to var newTask. This task however never gets scheduled or run when the original task won't result with an Exception. you should first assign the original task to newTask and then call newTask.ContinueWith(...., TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

Comment: thanks for answer. my current way were also working. it was not like waiting forever. however i modified the code as you said and now i check i see running. though i did not feel any speed difference. still same. this is about crawling web pages.

Comment: if task is now in sleep, does its status return to WaitingForActivation?