# How to activate task in c#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library

I'am trying to consume a wcf in windows 8:
My code to consume the method generated by the WCF service:

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Maquette_MyAirport_Win8.FlightService.CitiesResponse> 
    GetAllCitiesAsync(Maquette_MyAirport_Win8.FlightService.BaseRequest request)
{
    return base.Channel.GetAllCitiesAsync(request);
}
```

is

```
public testproxy()
{
    _client = new FlightInfoServiceClient(Maquette_MyAirport_Win8.FlightService.FlightInfoServiceClient.EndpointConfiguration.wsHttpBindingConfiguration);
    BaseRequest req = new BaseRequest();
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Maquette_MyAirport_Win8.FlightService.CitiesResponse> CitiesResponse = _client.GetAllCitiesAsync( new BaseRequest());
    CitiesResponse.ContinueWith(task => citiesL = task.Result.Cities.FirstOrDefault(););

}
```

The status of the task citiesResponse is "WaitingForACtivation" and Result="Not yet Computed"

How can I Activate the task and how can i obtain the result??

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your generated code. Normaly the task should run as soon as you got it back - maybe you can try to step through the generated code in your debuger to find out where the problem is

Comment: You may have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255187/task-status-waitingforactivation-what-does-this-mean) too...

Comment: When is the status of the `Task` the way you describe? Inside `testproxy()` or in the continuation? If it's inside `testproxy()`, then that could be correct behavior and you don't have to do anything to activate the `Task`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you have to add async and await to get the result type instead of Task type??

It should be something like this:

```
var result = await _client.GetAllCitiesAsync( new BaseRequest());
```

And in the method you should add async

Comment: See and example here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/piyushjo/archive/2011/09/22/wcf-in-win8-metro-styled-apps-absolutely-supported.aspx

Comment: `Task` predates `async`-`await`, you don't have to use it to get the result of the `Task`, there are other ways to do it.

Comment: I know there are other ways to get the result of the Task. I think it's a common issue that developers with .net 4 background don't know yet that the proper way to do it is with async - await..

Comment: But that's not the “proper” way, it's just one of the ways to do it.

Comment: Ok.. Then  "another way to do it".

Comment: I think s/he was looking for the await - async approach. Thanks for the -1.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509992/how-can-i-set-cilentcredentials-in-wcf

Comment: The code in the question was fine. Using `async` might improve it, but it doesn't fix it. I do think that proposing an alternative without explaining what's actually going on is not a good answer.

Comment: Of course it fixes it. Read the question: "How can I Activate the task and how can i obtain the result??" If you use the async-await approach, it returns the objects once the Tasks have finished, so you don't get "Not Yet computed".

Comment: By the way.. You are right, maybe I should have explained this in my answer.