# How can I set ClientCredentials?

Tags: c#, wcf, credentials

I'm trying to consume a WCF service:

The config of the service is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netNamedPipeBinding>
                <binding name="netNamedPipeEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netNamedPipeBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="netTcpEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false"
                    transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsHttpBindingConfiguration" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://webapppro-v11/FlightInfoWebService/FlightInfoService.svc"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpEndpoint"
                contract="FlightInfoService" name="netTcpEndpoint" />
            <endpoint address="net.pipe://webapppro-v11/FlightInfoWebService/FlightInfoService.svc"
                binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="netNamedPipeEndpoint"
                contract="FlightInfoService" name="netNamedPipeEndpoint" />
            <endpoint address="http://webapppro-v11/FlightInfoWebService/FlightInfoService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfiguration"
                contract="FlightInfoService" name="wsHttpBindingConfiguration" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I try to call the service:

```
public async void LoadCities()
{
    _client = new FlightInfoServiceClient(Maquette_MyAirport_Win8.FlightService.FlightInfoServiceClient.EndpointConfiguration.wsHttpBindingConfiguration, "http://servuucs.fr/FlightInfoWebService/FlightInfoService.svc");

    var citiesResponse = await _client.GetAllCitiesAsync(new BaseRequest());
    var  myCities = citiesResponse.Cities;
}
```

I catch this exception:

> ERROR: UnAuthorizedAccess description:You are not authorized to access this service

How can I set my ClientCredentials?

Comment: Please post your entire `<system.servicemodel/>` config. Also please format it so it's readable. Don't rely on the community to fix your formatting. Thanks

Comment: I updated my config, any suggestion please?

Comment: Heading and question description are different

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As @Paciv noted in a comment, you can do this through code. Set them with the property [ClientCredentials.Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.clientcredentials.windows.aspx), something like this:

```
_client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Domain = "warzone42";
_client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "user1428798";
_client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "p@ssw0rd";
```

Setting the credentials in code is of course unwise. If you don't set the Windows user programmatically as above, I believe the credentials from the user running the client are sent accross (which is perhaps a more typical situation?).

Note that if you're setting credentials in code you may in fact be looking for [UserName authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131.aspx).

Comment: Could be. But it answers your question ("How can I set client credentials?"), though.

Comment: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0aac0110-187e-4a00-a597-f15b768cf16c/passing-client-credentials-to-wcf-service](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0aac0110-187e-4a00-a597-f15b768cf16c/passing-client-credentials-to-wcf-service)

Comment: @lordkain (Apart from that my answer is 4 years old-) I'm not sure what you mean. Are those example credentials in my answer secure? Heck no. Are the SecureString entries? Nope. Is it safe to hardcode credentials in code? Probably not. Is it safe in general to set credentials using code? I sure hope so :D. Is using Windows.ClientCredential secure enough? That depends on your requirements and context; not something we can answer for you.

Comment: @Jeroen. 4 years :) I was just wondering about alternatives security wise. This is not the place for this discussion.

Comment: This will work *only* if the service `clientCredentialType` set to `Windows`. Note that you may use other ways to set `username` and `password` (such as `_client.ClientCredentials.UserName`)