# C# How to use WSDL-Service

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

i want to use a WSDL-Service, but i've never done this before. I have to use a certificate, but don't know how to implement this.

I did the following steps:

1. Added service reference
2. inserted the link to the online wsdl file
3. he got it and i selected O.K
4. Now i can use the namespace "ServiceReference1" in my project

When i want to call the Login-Method, then i get a error and vs tells me, that more informations are on the "faultDetailString." but how can i get these informations?

```
ServiceReference1.SessionWSIClient client = new ServiceReference1.SessionWSIClient();
string result = client.Login(this.transaktionsId, this.benutzerId, this.pin);
```

Comment: Maybe add a try/catch block to get the exception and its detail.
For your certificate part of the question, do you got any method/parameter in your "client" object?

Comment: this is the output from the exception (not usefull)
http://pastebin.com/dhw9PW9x

and this methods / parameters are in the object
http://s2.postimg.org/6uwyea509/Unbenannt.jpg

Comment: Sorry, don't have access to pastebin links here (network filter).
For the method and parameters, `ClientCredentials` may be an interesting field to work with your certificate (for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12509992/how-can-i-set-clientcredentials)