# Loading images from instagram api. Getting status WaitingForActivation

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a few images filtered by tag using [InstaSharp](http://instasharp.github.io/InstaSharp/Documentation/html/c688497b-86a9-4040-b9e0-addb972beed8.htm):

```
Task<MediasResponse> b = GetImages("pet");

var c = b.Status;
```

I have the following:

```
public async Task<MediasResponse> GetImages(String tag) {

  var clientId = "xyz";
  var clientSecret = "xyz";

  InstagramConfig config = new InstagramConfig(clientId, clientSecret);

  InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags media = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags(config);

  MediasResponse pictures = await media.Recent(tag);

  return pictures;

}
```

When I run this code I keep getting the error:

```
Status = WaitingForActivation
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255187/task-status-waitingforactivation-what-does-this-mean

Comment: I have read those posts but I am not sure how to solve my problem ... Could you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong. That simply means that `GetImages` hasn't completed yet.

To (asynchronously) wait for it to complete and retrieve the response, use `await`:

```
Task<MediasResponse> b = GetImages("pet");
var c = await b;
```

Comment: I tried that and I get the following error: Error 1 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'. I do not know what is wrong since GetImages is async and has Task

Comment: Read the exception message again. The *calling* method must be `async`.